# VS 2008 The operation could not be completed. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, iis

On updating my working copy from SVN. I get this error.

The operation could not be completed. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

This error also corrupts my all reference in main project ( not in DAL not in BLL). and I have to add all (.net or 3rd party dlls) again.

[VS 2008 Error http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/8871/errork.png](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/8871/errork.png)

It was working OK but I am getting this error from the last couple of days.

If anybody can help!

**EDIT:** I have increased Virtual Memory and now I am not getting this error. I will check this for couple of days and again inform you people.

Comment: It is not exact dublicate, but is similar to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995906/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-visualstudio-2008  still I have no exact answer on it, and I suppose it is a bug in VS. Usually I restart VS every time when I see this error and then it works fine for a 3-4 hours until next error... :(

Comment: I have 3 GB memory. The only solution is to close and launch Visual Studio again.

Comment: I restared vs to fix, worked great. My fault in the first place for trying to open a 38meg Cobol.net file (generated, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hot to fix the reason of this bug, but you can try to increase the memory and see if this will help you to avoid this bug or not

See https://serverfault.com/questions/27352/are-there-any-drawbacks-of-3gb-switch-in-boot-ini-for-32bit-windows about using /3Gb switch in Boot.ini in order to get more memory for a process running on 32bit system.